# Cambiar color StatusBar y como argregar setAlpha

Tags: android

Bueno llevo un tiempo intentanto poner el alpha al status bar 
pero no puedo lograrlo, quisera hacer asi como la toolbar con setAlpha()

```
toolbar.getBackground().setAlpha(intColor);
```

pero no encuentra una propiedad similar para la status bar, intente con el siguiente código pero lo he logrado mi objetivo;

```
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.alpha(intColor));
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: con alpha te refiereres en hacer la toolbar con un poco de transparencia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recuerda que 
`window.setStatusBarColor()` funciona para Android 5.0 y posterior. Usa el método `Color.argb()` para definir el `alpha`:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
       int alpha = 150; //valor 0 a 255.
 getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.argb(alpha, 250, 120, 0));


    }
```

Con respecto al método `getBackground()` del `toolBar` es mejor usar `setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);`

Defines un color en colors.xml para crear el ColorDrawable:

```
  ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.mi_color));
```

defines un alpha entre 0 y 255 para tu `ColorDrawable` :

```
colorDrawable.setAlpha(150);
```

defines el `ColorDrawable` a tu toolBar:

```
mToolbar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
```

Comment: Hola @Elenasys sin funciona pero lo que quisiera lograr es que a medida que se hace el scroll el status bar de transparente vuelva a su color inicial y eso no puedo lograrglo por que no encuentro un atributo como el del toolbar pero tampoco da con este                  layout.getStatusBarBackground().setAlpha(intColor);

Answer (score 0):

Intenta añadir el color por Hexagesimal y añadiéndole dos caracteres más al inicio logras el alpha. Aquí una tabla sobre esos dos caracteres:

```
     Hex Opacity Values
     100% — FF
     95% — F2
     90% — E6
     85% — D9
     80% — CC
     75% — BF
     70% — B3
     65% — A6
     60% — 99
     55% — 8C
     50% — 80
     45% — 73
     40% — 66
     35% — 59
     30% — 4D
     25% — 40
     20% — 33
     15% — 26
     10% — 1A
     5% — 0D
     0% — 00
```